# aws eks and fargate pricing of the workload without "limits"

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I'm a little bit confused about pricing and cpu/memory allocations for the **aws eks on fargate**.

### For example:

```
fargate_profiles = {
  coredns-fargate-profile = {
    name = "coredns"
    selectors = [{
        namespace = "argo-cd"
        labels = {
          app.kubernetes.io/name="argocd-server"
        }        
    }]
    subnets = flatten([module.vpc.outputs.private_subnets])
  }
}
```

#### then I set argocd-server requests only (no limits)

```
Requests:
  cpu:      256m
  memory:   256Mi
```

during 24h the argocd server jumps to 4vcpu/8Gi only for 2 hours (14:00-16:00). Will fargate scale automatically to 4vcpu/8Gi? or it can't go beyond 0.25vcpu?

#### what would be the cost I'm paying to fargate?

am I right to assume that it is:

- 22h = $0.272 USD
- 2h = $0.395 USD

so would the total per day be: $0.667? (used https://fargate.org/)

Answer (score 0):

ok that is impossible as eks runs pods with guaranteed priority

> Since Amazon EKS Fargate runs only one pod per node, the scenario of evicting pods in case of fewer resources doesn't occur. All Amazon EKS Fargate pods run with guaranteed priority, so the requested CPU and memory must be equal to the limit for all of the containers. For more information, see Configure Quality of Service for Pods in the Kubernetes documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-pod-configuration.html

so that particular use case should have higher requests to accomodate potential spike to avoid throttling.